# Repeat the value for duplicate records in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with duplicate Id’s, but the status message is repeated only for a couple of id’s. Example below

```
 Id           Status
101         Single entry and multiple items
101         Multiple items
101         Single items
101         
101         
501
502       Multiple
502
```

I would like to have the ‘Status’ messages repeated for the other two Id’s also (it can be either of the messages)

I thought of creating two datasets with and without ‘Status’ and then merge them on ‘Id’

Is there any simple solution to this?

Comment: What do you want to do if there is a blank status followed by a non-blank one?

Comment: I have already sorted the data to be in status and then blank by id

Comment: Are there any ids where every status is blank? What then?

Comment: Then keep them blank. Row 6 in the above example

Comment: What should happen if the 101 id was 601 and came after 502 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot understand where this would be a reasonable thing to do, but it is pretty easy.  You could make a new variable and use RETAIN.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by id ;
  if first.id then new=status ;
  if not missing(status) then new=status ;
  retain new ;
  rename new=status status=old_status;
run;
```

Or you could do it using merge.

```
data want ;
  merge have(drop=status) have(keep=id status where=(not missing(status)));
  by id;
run;
```